# How would I test this promise based code with jest?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

How would I test this code in jest? I'd like to make sure that the error and success of the passed promise is being called as needed. I'm sure it's something sorta simple, but it's driving me crazy. Thanks very much.

```
handleStatusChangeRequest (changeEntryStatus) {
  return changeEntryStatus().then(() => {
    this.handleStatusChangeSuccess()
  }).catch(err => {
    this.handleErrorDisplay(err)
  })
}
```

Comment: What do you have in mind for assertions? Snapshots, mocking and verifying method calls, ...?

Comment: It's just the full jest test suite . . . not bringing in mocha or anything like that. Just within the `react-create-app` (sp?) tool chain.

Answer (score 2):

If your code uses promises, there is a nice way to handle asynchronous tests. Just return a `promise` from your test, and `Jest` will wait for that `promise` to resolve.
***If the promise is rejected, the test will automatically fail.***

For example, let's say that `changeData`, instead of using a callback, returns a `promise` that is supposed to resolve to the string *"status has been successfully modified"*.

Be sure to **`return`** the `promise` - if you omit this return statement, your test will complete before your `changeData()` -[*async function*] completes.

***Here's a convenient and easy to follow pattern***

```
test('if the data is changed', () => {
  return changeData().then((data) => {
    expect(data).toBe('status has been successfully modified');
  });
})
```

Happy testing :)

Comment: Sorry, not seeing it. The code in your first example is not valid js? Missing something after the `handleStatusChangeRequest` call. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This could be refactored, but for the sake of demonstration, I left the repeating bits in.

In `example.spec.js`, the callback, `changeEntryStatus`, is stubbed to return a promise. In order to check if other instance methods (`this.method`) were called, they are first mocked, then assertions are called on the mock after running the method being tested. Learn more in the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started). (See my thoughts on mocking methods of the unit being tested at the bottom.)

[Run the example on repl.it.](https://repl.it/@median_man/SO-Jest-Example)

**example.js:**

```
class Example {
  handleStatusChangeRequest(changeEntryStatus) {
    return changeEntryStatus().then(() => {
      this.handleStatusChangeSuccess()
    }).catch(err => {
      this.handleErrorDisplay(err)
    })
  }

  handleStatusChangeSuccess() {
    console.log('stubbed handleStatusChangeSuccess')
  }

  handleErrorDisplay(error) {
    console.log('stubbed handleErrorDisplay:', error)
  }
}

module.exports = Example;
```

**example.spec.js:**

```
const Example = require('./entryStatus')
describe('handleStatusChangeRequest', () => {
  it('should run the changeEntryStatus callback', () => {
    const {handleStatusChangeRequest} = new Example()
    const stub = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue()

    handleStatusChangeRequest(stub)

    // must return because handleStatusChangeRequest is asynchronous
    return expect(stub).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });

  it('should call example.handleStatusChangeSuccess', async () => {
    const example = new Example()
    const stub = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue()
    example.handleStatusChangeSuccess = jest.fn()

    await example.handleStatusChangeRequest(stub)

    expect(example.handleStatusChangeSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

  it('should call example.handleErrorDisplay', async () => {
    const example = new Example()
    const fakeError = { code: 'fake_error_code' }
    const stub = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(fakeError)
    example.handleErrorDisplay = jest.fn()


    await example.handleStatusChangeRequest(stub)

    expect(example.handleErrorDisplay).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(example.handleErrorDisplay).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeError)
  });
});
```

**Opinionated Disclaimer**: Mocking methods of the unit under test is a smell. Consider checking for the expected effects of calling `handleStatusChangeSuccess` and `handleErrorDisplay` instead of checking to see if they were called. Then don't even expose those methods publicly unless consumers of the class need access.

Comment: Hey cool, I like this. I have gone with a similar approach.

Hmmmm but I do test the other functions in a series of different tests that aren't tied into this promise sequence. I think mocks here are good because I just want to make sure the sequence is running as expected in the success/error scenarios. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

> **Opinionated Disclaimer:** Mocking methods of the unit under test is a
>   smell. Consider checking for the expected effects of calling
>   `handleStatusChangeSuccess` and `handleErrorDisplay` instead of checking
>   to see if they were called. Then don't even expose those methods
>   publicly unless consumers of the class need access.

I *wholeheartedly agree* with webprojohn's disclaimer. Mocks are a smell as tests should assert the *behavior* of the code, not its *implementation*. Testing the latter makes the code brittle to change.

Stepping off my soapbox... :) We're looking for a way to test an asynchronous method. I'm not sure what assertions your tests should make to verify the behavior inside `handleStatusChangeSuccess()` and `handleErrorDisplay(err)` so the example below leaves a comment where those assertions would go. The following uses [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [`Promise.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) to trigger the outcomes to test. I've used async/await, Jest has [other async examples in their docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async).

```
const Example = require('./example')

describe('handleStatusChangeRequest', () => {
  it('should resolve successfully', async () => {
    const {handleStatusChangeRequest} = new Example();
    const resolvePromise = () => Promise.resolve();

    await handleStatusChangeRequest(resolvePromise);

    // resolution assertions here
  });

  it('should resolve errors', async () => {
    const {handleStatusChangeRequest} = new Example();
    const fakeError = new Error('eep');
    const rejectPromise = () => Promise.reject(fakeError);

    // if your method doesn't throw, we can remove this try/catch
    // block and the fail() polyfill
    try {
      await example.handleStatusChangeRequest(rejectPromise);

      // if we don't throw our test shouldn't get here, so we
      // polyfill a fail() method since Jest doesn't give us one.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2129
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // rejection assertions here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm cool. :) I like the try catch in the test. I should try that approach more.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I have looks so:

**Success tests**

```
const instance = el.find(EntryToolBar).instance()
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleStatusChangeSuccess')

await instance.handleStatusChangeRequest(() => Promise.resolve('cool man'))

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

**Error tests**

```
const instance = el.find(EntryToolBar).instance()
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleErrorDisplay')

await instance.handleStatusChangeRequest(() => Promise.reject(Error('shit')))
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

As I stated above, the `handleStatusChangeSuccess` and `handleError` methods are test else where with some snapshots (they just set state and render out some different jsx). I feel pretty good about this. I'm using spys/mocks, but I'm testing the implementation functions elsewhere. Sufficient?

Comment: From the question, it seems like both methods are internals of your component. Is there a reason either should be exposed in the public interface of the component? If not, I'd refactor the snapshots to become part of the tests for `handleStatusChangeRequest` and make the internal methods private. Test the behavior of your public interface, "don't test your privates."

Comment: Nope, that's true, they could both be private methods. Maybe static. Why don't you test private methods?

Comment: It's a testing philosophy: tests should warn us when we break what the code was intended to do, not _how_ it did it. If a test fails because we rename a method (e.g. here would be `handleErrorDisplay` -> `handleError`) but we didn't change the method internals, it's considered a bad failure or false positive. Hope that helps, we can take this to private chat if you'd like to discuss further.

Comment: Hmmm I think I would consider that a really good failure. If I change names of things, I definitely want errors to raise on things that are reliant on that name.

Thanks very much for your help all along. lol You'll likely get emails from me harassing you about other code things in the future, no doubt.

Comment: Nah, more likely the component would still work when you check it manually but the tests fail. IDEs don't always catch string usages like jest.spyOn(component, 'handleErrorDisplay'). But anyway, good luck and happy testing.